# mvc: displaying json data in mvc view from controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

Hi guys I am facing a problem in displaying json data from controller to view.
json data is displayed in the browser. It is not using master page and
my view is not a partial view. I don't understand what the problem  is

my controller is as follows

```
public JsonResult Grid()
{
    var data = en.customers.Select(x => new ProductModel()
    {
        fname = x.fname,
        lname = x.lname,
        username = x.username,
        password = x.password

    }).ToList();

    return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

my view is as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $.getJSON("/Home/Grid", null, function (data) {
            var items = '<table><tr><th>FNAME</th><th>LNAME</th> <th>USERNAME</th><th>PASSWORD</th></tr>';
            $.each(data, function (i, cus) {
                items += "<tr><td>" + cus.fname + "</td><td>" + cus.lname +  "</td><td>" + cus.username + "</td><td>" + cus.password + "</td></tr>";
            });
               items += "</table>";

            $('#mytbl').html(items);
        });

    });
```

Comment: can we see the mytbl tag code?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url : "/Home/Grid",// url
        type : "GET", // GET or POST
        data : {}, // null data
        dataType : "json",// expected type in return
        success : function(data){
            var table = '<table><tr><th>FNAME</th><th>LNAME</th> <th>USERNAME</th><th>PASSWORD</th></tr>';
            for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                table += "<tr><td>" + data[i].fname + "</td><td>" + data[i].lname +  "</td><td>" + data[i].username + "</td><td>" + data[i].password + "</td></tr>";
            }
            table += "</table>";
            $('#mytbl').html(table); 
        },
        error : function(data){
            alert("Internal Server Error:\n"+data);
        },
    });
});
</script>
```

Try this...

Comment: thank u aneesh but still i am getting same problem. i am using chrome browser, data is displayed in the form of json array on plain browser window

Comment: can you show me the json that you are receiving.i dont know the server script that you are using.So if you can provide the response, it will be very easy to solve it.....
NOTE : The success function is only called when the receiving data is perfect json.If any server error occurs, it will execute the error part, which i have added just now.The code is updated.Please note that.